# how to restricte input to make sure it is a number with cout and cin in c++?

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and got confused about the following code which is excerpted from the book a complete guide to C++.

```
//Ref2.cpp
//Demonstrating functions with parameters
//of reference type.
//--------------------------------------------------
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
                                                                       // Prototypes:
bool getClient( string& name, long& nr);
void putClient( const string& name, const long& nr);




int main()
{
    string clientName;
    long clientNr;                                                    // client number?
    cout << "\nTo input and output client data \n"
         << endl;
    if( getClient( clientName, clientNr))

        putClient( clientName, clientNr);
    else
        cout << "Invalid input!" << endl;
    return 0;
}

// getClient function definition
bool getClient( string& name, long& nr)                 // pass by reference, both name and nr are references to the function arguments clientName and clientNr
{
     cout << "\nTo input client data!\n"
          << " Name: ";
     if( !getline( cin, name)) return false;
     cout << " Number: ";
     if( !( cin >> nr)) return false;
     return true;
}



// putClient function Definition
void putClient( const string& name, const long& nr)  // pass by reference, both name and nr are references to the function arguments clientName and clientNr
{
     cout << "\n-------- Client Data ---------\n"
          << "\n Name:"; 
     cout << name << "\n Number: "; 
     cout << nr << endl;
}
```

with the above code, the following is the output of running it.

```
To input and output client data 


To input client data!
 Name: fjdkljfdlfjdlfjdljf dfjdlfjdlfjdlfjdl dfj
 Number: 123435jjjjj

-------- Client Data ---------

 Name:fjdkljfdlfjdlfjdljf dfjdlfjdlfjdlfjdl dfj
 Number: 123435
```

My question is: the user input `12345jjjjj` for the client Number entry. How come when printing out, it has changed into 12345?

Comment: How exactly do you expect to print a `long` value, and get `12345jjjjj` as the result from this? What does it mean to have a `long` value whose value is `12345jjjjj`, so you see this when you print its value? If you think about this, you will figure out the answer all by yourself.

Comment: `cin >> nr` reads as many characters as can be interpreted as representing an integer; it stops at the first character that cannot be part of an integer. In your example, it does *not* read `12345jjjjj` - it reads `12345`, stops at the first `j` and leaves it, and subsequent characters, in the stream, to be picked up by the next input operation (if any).